# Permission denied when importing a database

Tags: postgresql

This is my first time here and i have a question.
I am working with postgresql on windows 8 for the first time.
I am trying to import a database into postgresql with the command line.

Type in:

```
psql -U username -d databasename -a -f path to the database (C:\Users\Username\Downloads\database
```

After that i type in my password for the username.
then i get this error:

```
C:\Users\Username\Downloads\database: Permission denied.
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Apparently, you don't have access to the file with the DB dump.  Can you open it in an editor?

Answer (score 0):

`-f C:\Users\Username\Downloads\database`  does not make sense.  You don't specify the "file" for a database. You specify the **name** of a database as you did with the `-d` parameter.

`-f` is used to specify a *SQL script* that you want to execute using `psql`

To "import" a database, you need to specify the actual SQL file, something like:

```
-f C:\Users\Username\Downloads\database\the_dump.sql
```

This assumes that you actually did download a "SQL" script and not a binary dump created with `pg_dump -Fc`. If that is the case you need to use `pg_restore`, not `psql`